# How to add a linear-gradient in an image using CSS?

Tags: html, css, linear-gradients

I have this snippet code. I want to add a linear-gradient to my image using Css. But I tried this code so far but the linear-gradient doesn't add anything. Do I have to use position:absolute or relative to overlay my linear-gradient inside my image? please help.

I use this

Please add this image to the image tag because jsfiddle doesn't have an option to add local files and upload it. Sorry for the inconvenience.

```css
.container { width: 1000px;padding: 0;margin: 0 auto;}
.slideshow {position: relative; background: linear-gradient(to left, rgba(0,0,0,0), rgba(0,0,0,0.1), rgba(0,0,0,0.8));}
.slideshow img {border: 3px solid #153f27;border-radius: 5px;-webkit-box-shadow: 4px 3px 5px 0px rgba(168,168,168,1);-moz-box-shadow: 4px 3px 5px 0px rgba(168,168,168,1);box-shadow: 4px 3px 5px 0px rgba(168,168,168,1);}
.slogan {position: absolute; top: 30px; padding: 25px 20px;}
.slogan h1 {font: bold 30px Arial;color: #fff;}
.slogan p {width: 490px;font: bold 17px Arial;color: #fff;padding: 4px 0px;}
```

```html
<div id="banner">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="slideshow">
      <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/KOi78.jpg" alt="Lorem Ipsum">
      <div class="slogan">
        <h1>Lorem Ipsum</h1>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute
          irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to do that is to use a pseudo element, like `::after`.

First I added a pseudo element on the `slideshow` element for the gradient, and positioned it using `position: absolute` (and `position: relative` on the `slideshow`), then by setting different `z-index` on the pseudo and the `slogan`, layered it between the image and text.

```css
.container {
  width: 1000px;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.slideshow {
  position: relative;
}

.slideshow::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: linear-gradient(to left, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8));
  z-index: 1;
}

.slideshow img {
  border: 3px solid #153f27;
  border-radius: 5px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 4px 3px 5px 0px rgba(168, 168, 168, 1);
  -moz-box-shadow: 4px 3px 5px 0px rgba(168, 168, 168, 1);
  box-shadow: 4px 3px 5px 0px rgba(168, 168, 168, 1);
}

.slogan {
  position: absolute;
  top: 30px;
  padding: 25px 20px;
  z-index: 2;
}

.slogan h1 {
  font: bold 30px Arial;
  color: #fff;
}

.slogan p {
  width: 490px;
  font: bold 17px Arial;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 4px 0px;
}
```

```html
<div id="banner">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="slideshow">
      <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/KOi78.jpg" alt="Lorem Ipsum">
      <div class="slogan">
        <h1>Lorem Ipsum</h1>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute
          irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is what I've been looking for sir. Thank you for this. How to achieve this? is it about the positioning and the arrangement of codes?

Comment: @LaurenceAlbano Updated my answer with an explanation

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative option, instead of using an img tag you can place the image as a background for your slideshow div. CSS backgrounds can have multiple layers so to speak, by defining multiple backgrounds they stack on top of each other. I suggest removing your image tag and using the code below:

```css
.container {
  width: 1000px;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.slideshow {
  position: relative;
  background: linear-gradient(to left, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8)), url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/KOi78.jpg') no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  height: 400px;
  /*CSS from Img tag not applied to slideshow*/
  border: 3px solid #153f27;
  border-radius: 5px;
  box-shadow: 4px 3px 5px 0px rgba(168, 168, 168, 1);
}

.slideshow img {
  border: 3px solid #153f27;
  border-radius: 5px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 4px 3px 5px 0px rgba(168, 168, 168, 1);
  -moz-box-shadow: 4px 3px 5px 0px rgba(168, 168, 168, 1);
  box-shadow: 4px 3px 5px 0px rgba(168, 168, 168, 1);
}

.slogan {
  position: absolute;
  top: 30px;
  padding: 25px 20px;
  z-index: 2;
}

.slogan h1 {
  font: bold 30px Arial;
  color: #fff;
}

.slogan p {
  width: 490px;
  font: bold 17px Arial;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 4px 0px;
}
```

```html
<div id="banner">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="slideshow">
      <div class="slogan">
        <h1>Lorem Ipsum</h1>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute
          irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is also a good example sir, but I need an image tag for it. Because I will do some javascript/jquery in it to animate and do slideshow to each image automatically. Thank you for this. (y)